# List of rc keys in matplotlib. Tick label rotations

Tags: python, matplotlib

Where can I find a full list of rc keys in matplotlib?

I found [this document](http://urania.udea.edu.co/sitios/astronomia-2.0/pages/descargas.rs/files/descargasdt5vi/Cursos/CursosElectivos/FisicaAstrofisicaComputacional/2009-2/Documentacion/matplotlib/users/customizing.html) that shows an example with many (perhaps all?) keys, but I am unable to find the 
one that controls the rotation of the xaxis major tick labels.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have a reason you want to use rc keys for this, but you can set xtick rotation via the plt.xticks(rotation=[degrees of desired rotation]) command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current params are in `mpl.rcParams`. Defaults are in `mpl.rcParamsDefault`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a particular reason why the property `setp( ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=30)` cannot be changed through `rc` keys? (I couldn't find the keyword `rotation` in the list). Is it considered to be a different type of property for some reason?

Comment: No idea why, but it is the case that not everything can be configured through the `rc` keys.